# Gitlab API: How to generate the private token

Tags: api, curl, gitlab, gitlab-api

This is what I tried:

```
curl http://git.ep.petrobras.com.br/api/v3/session --data-urlencode 'login=myUser&password=myPass'
```

Answer:

`{"message":"401 Unauthorized"}`

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The problem is the `data-urlencode` CURL option. Since it's an HTTP POST you don't need to URL encode the data, and is actually encoding the `&` into `&amp;` and causing your issue. Instead use the `--data` option.

```
curl http://git.ep.petrobras.com.br/api/v3/session --data 'login=myUser&password=myPass'
```

Also, be careful sending credentials over plain HTTP. It could be easily sniffed.

Comment: For anyone reading this and wondering how to do this securely: curl supports HTTPS just fine, so simply replace the protocol with `https://` (assuming your gitlab server supports this).

Answer (score 10):

This is how:

```
$ curl http://git.ep.petrobras.com.br/api/v3/session/ --data-urlencode 'login=myUser' --data-urlencode 'password=myPass'
```

The solution pointed out by Steven doesn't work if your username or password contains characters that have to be urleencoded. The `name=content` format will urlencode the `content` part (the `name` part has to be urlencoded but `login` and `password` are fine).

To actually retrieve the `private_token` you can pipe the output of curl into jq like this:

```
$ curl [as above] | jq --raw-output .private_token
x_the_private_token_value_x
```

This way you can easily use it in a shell script.

Also, as Steven pointed out already, please use https instead so that your password is not transmitted in clear text across the wire.

Answer (score 2):

Note: this workflow no longer works as of GitLab 8.6.0 as the default password has been removed.

Changelog: https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-ce/blob/master/CHANGELOG#L205

I only just noticed this and raised the issue. Leaving this note here to hopefully save someone else some time. Hopefully, this is a decision that will be reviewed and reverted.

Discussion/issue: https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-ce/issues/1980

Comment: Aral, I just ran into this issue as well. Did you ever find a resolution to it?