# Download from private GitLab without API

Tags: python, session, authentication, cookies, gitlab

I need to download a file from a private GitLab.

I already saw this post:
    [Download from a GitLab private repository](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24463229/download-from-a-gitlab-private-repository)

But I cannot use the API, since I dont have the needed IDs to download the files.
In fact, I need to download them by theirs HTTP raw urls, like:

```
http://gitlab.private.com/group/repo_name/raw/master/diagrams/test.plantuml
```

Since I turned on authentication, every time I try to access something programatically, I am redirected to login page.
I wrote a Python script to mimic the login process, obtain the authenticity_token and the _gitlab_session cookie, but still not working.

If I grab a session cookie from my Chrome browser after a successful login, everything works like a charm (from the file download perspective) on Python and even curl.

So, any help is apreciated to obtain this cookie, os a different approach. To use the API I would first need to struggle among all repos performing strings matches so I can find the proper IDs. This is the last option.

Tks
Marco

Comment: Do you really need a Python script to fake login ? You can login through the API: send a `POST /session` with login & password as parameters; and obtain the `private_token`. Take a look [here](http://doc.gitlab.com/ce/api/session.html)

Comment: Yes, I know I can use the API. But if I do that, I need to download the file via API. Then, I will need to parse groups/repos to transform my groups/repos names to IDs. FakeLogin is getting worse as time passes...

Answer (score 0):

First generate a Personal Access Token from your settings page: `/profile/personal_access_tokens`. Make sure it has the **read_repository** scope.

Then you can use one of two methods, replacing `PRIVATETOKEN` with the token you  acquired:

1. Pass a `Private-Token` header in your request. E.g.

   ```
   curl --header "Private-Token: PRIVATETOKEN" http://gitlab.private.com/group/repo_name/raw/master/diagrams/test.plantuml
   ```
2. Add a `private_token` query string to your request. E.g.

   ```
   curl 'http://gitlab.private.com/group/repo_name/raw/master/diagrams/test.plantuml?private_token=PRIVATETOKEN'
   ```

Comment: can anyone verify that this actually works? for me it doesnt