# Capability to NPM install private gitlab repo

Tags: npm, gitlab

I am trying to use one of my private gitlab repositories as npm package. I am successfully able to do it when access to the repo is public but not with a private one.

Can someone help me understand the authentication mechanism. I cannot use ssh because we run the application on heroku.

I have looked into:

- [using gitlab token to clone without authentication](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25409700/using-gitlab-token-to-clone-without-authentication)
- https://docs.gitlab.com/ce/user/project/new_ci_build_permissions_model.html
- [Download from a GitLab private repository](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24463229/download-from-a-gitlab-private-repository)

But private token or gitlab ci runner token are not working.

Comment: Did you find a solution to your issue? I'm having the same problem

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/43774869/2179157