# Cannot download file from gitlab using command line

Tags: curl, command-line, gitlab, wget, okta

I have an internal deployment of gitlab: https://gitlab.corp.mycompany.com/project/account/config-file/repo/blob/long_alphanumeric_numer/my_wanted_file

I want to download "my_wanted_file" via command line. It contains configuration stuff.

**I tried so far:**

```
curl -o https://gitlab.corp.mycompany.com/project/account/configfile/repo/blob/master/my_wanted_file

wget https://gitlab.corp.mycompany.com/project/account/configfile/repo/blob/master/my_wanted_file
```

**Then I clicked "permalink" and tried again with:**

````
curl -OL https://gitlab.corp.mycompany.com/project/account/configfile/repo/blob/long_alphanumeric_numer/my_wanted_file

wget https://gitlab.corp.mycompany.com/project/account/configfile/repo/blob/long_alphanumeric_numer/my_wanted_file```

curl 'Private-Token: my_private_token' https://gitlab.corp.mycompany.com/project/account/configfile/repo/blob/long_alphanumeric_numer/my_wanted_file
````

Using curl --header 'Private-Token: my_private_token' plus url, returns this msg:

```
<html><body>You are being 
<a href="https://gitlab.corp.my_company.com/users/sign_in">redirected</a>.</body></html>
```

In all cases I do get a weird file with java script stuff but never the config file content that `my_wanted_file` currently shows in gitlab.

I think it's important to let you know guys that I'm connecting to this private gitlab deployment via okta. Not sure if that is introducing some noise in the middle and, therefore a different command needs to be supplied.

Could you please advice?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to download a single file from GitLab?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56943327/how-to-download-a-single-file-from-gitlab)

Comment: Using --header and my private token, which btw I used before, returns this msg: <html><body>You are being <a href="https://gitlab.corp.my_company.com/users/sign_in">redirected</a>.</body></html>

Comment: It's because you don't use the API url. See my answer above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For such case, it's better to use Gitlab API and specially [Repository File API](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/api/repository_files.html#get-file-from-repository) to get file from repository :

```
curl --header "PRIVATE-TOKEN: <your_access_token>" "https://gitlab.corp.mycompany.com/api/v4/projects/<project_id>/repository/files/my_wanted_file?ref=master"
```

Create your personal token following these [instructions](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/profile/personal_access_tokens.html#creating-a-personal-access-token).