# Gitlab API returning corrupted/incomplete tar.gz

Tags: curl, gitlab, wget, tar, gitlab-api

I am trying to download a tar.gz file from the repository of my company's gitlab instance. I am trying to do it with the commands wget and curl, but both seem to return a file that is not the correct one because tar -xf or tar -tvf throw unexpected end of file errors and I don't know why since 1 week ago this wasn't happening.

The HTTP status is 200 OK when I debug both commands.

Answer (score 1):

Are you trying to download the file from a private repository. You need to be an authenticated user to do this, unless it is a public repository.

You should retrieve the file by passing authentication token to curl request.

Have a look here, https://stackoverflow.com/a/25798157/12057816

Comment: Turns out the problem was due to the machine being out of disk space, it was generating faulty .tar.gz files and therefore i was getting those faulty .tar.gz